# Node.js Express - send array in json (res.json)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I got an app.get like that:

```
app.get('/orders/:pizzeriaID/:status', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const requestedOrderByPizzeriaID = req.params['pizzeriaID'];
    const requestedOrderByStatus = req.params['status'];
    console.log("STATUS" + requestedOrderByStatus);
    const client = await pool.connect();
    const result = await client.query('SELECT od.orderID, od.pizzaID, od.pizzaOrderQuantity, o.orderName, o.orderAddress, o.orderComment, o.orderPhone, o.orderEmail FROM ordersDetails od NATURAL JOIN pizzeria p  NATURAL join orders o WHERE p.pizzeriaID=\'' + requestedOrderByPizzeriaID + '\' AND o.orderStatus=\'' + requestedOrderByStatus + '\'');
    const results = (result) ? result.rows : null;
    res.json({results});
    client.release();
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send("Error " + err);
}});
```

In database model like that:
[DBModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LAr1.png)

It displays JSON like that: [JSON1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFe9A.png)

I would like to have only one object with orderid=1, inside of which there is a second json(array?) with pizzaID and pizzaOrderQuantity list in it.

Manner like this is wanted:

```
results:{ 
  orderid: 1,
  orderDetails: [{ 
   pizzaid: 1,
   pizzaorderquantity: 2,
    },
   pizzaid: 2,
   pizzaorderquantity: 4,
    },
   pizzaid: 3,
   pizzaorderquantity: 1,
    }],
   ordername: 'Karol Piwnicki',
   orderaddress: 'Rydla 26/30',
   ordercomment: 'Szybko poprosze',
   orderphone: '111-222-333',
   orderemail: 'mail@mail.com' }
```

I have been sitting with it for a while already, tried couple of ways found in tutorials and stack, but got no luck with it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Using `requestedOrderByPizzeriaID` and `requestedOrderByStatus` directly in the query without proper escaping is a really bad idea, as it can be used for sql injections. You should use prepared statements or placeholders instead. A user could use something like this `/orders/' OR TRUE OR '/:status` as url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by returning a json in SQL query and switching the res.json(), with res.send().

For reference, I used query like this:

```
const result = await client.query('select row_to_json(x) AS order 
FROM (select o.orderID, json_agg(json_build_object(\'pizzaID\',o.pizzaID, \'pizzaOrderQuantity\', o.pizzaOrderQuantity)) AS orderDetails, 
ord.orderName, ord.orderAddress, ord.orderComment, ord.orderPhone, ord.orderEmail FROM ordersDetails o 
NATURAL JOIN pizzeria p NATURAL JOIN orders ord 
WHERE p.pizzeriaID=\'' + requestedOrderByPizzeriaID + '\' GROUP BY o.orderID, ord.orderName, ord.orderAddress, ord.orderComment, ord.orderPhone, ord.orderEmail) as x');
```

Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascripts [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function in order to group the orders, and then [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to convert it back into an array.

```js
const json = Object.values(results.reduce((acc, order) => {
if (!acc[order.orderid]) {
    acc[order.orderid] = {
        orderid: order.orderid,
        orderDetails: []
    };
}
acc[order.orderid].orderDetails.push(order)
return acc
}, {}))

res.json(json);
```

[edit] Just edited the snippet so the output would be exactly the same